# CSS float problem

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to insert a ul li element inside a tab structure. Am not able to float li elements next to each other.

http://bakasura.in/king/elements/tabify/

**li.tab-content-ul-li** is not floating next to each other

**Updated**

[image]

the views li is dropping to the next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling your listitems li rather than l1 :)

Your HTML looks like

```
<l1 class="tab-content-ul-li">
```

Change all the 'l1' tags to 'li'

```
<li class="tab-content-ul-li"> ... </li>
```

And it should work

Comment: didnt get you.. can u plz elaborate

Comment: Your HTML looks like 

    <l1 class="tab-content-ul-li">

It should be

    <li class="tab-content-ul-li">

And then of course also your closing tags and other tags, you've used <l1> tags where in your css you target <li> tags

Comment: i have one more problem with float. i have updated the question.. it works fine here http://bakasura.in/king/ i a trying to insert a slide show inside tabs.. so doing it in a diff page.

Comment: That's because <ul> by default have a large left-padding. You can fix it by adding to the css of '#polaroid ul.tools' 'padding:0px;'